# Jquery datepicker validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to check if user hasn't chosen value from calendar. I am using such code:

```
$('#" . $id . "').datepicker({
   dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy',
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   onClose: function(selectedDate,el) {
      if(selectedDate == ''){
         $(el).addClass('error');
      }
      else{
         $('#" . $id . "').removeClass('error');
      }
}});
```

**UPD**
How can I addClass inside onCLose?

Comment: Why are you using the `blur` event, the datepicker probably has it's own events ?

Comment: Is it really matter? Blur works well

Comment: Clearly it's not, if probably fires before the value has changed, which is why you should be using the datepickers built in change event, and a variable that holds the previous value, to check if a new value was selected etc.

Comment: You are right. If I use onClose, I have correct value.